# Merging three lists into into one dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, merge

I need to merge three lists into one dictionary. These lists are from reading a txt file I formatted, and here is a snippet from that file:

```
maker =['Horsey', 'Ford', 'Overland', 'Scripps-Booth']

year = ['1899', '1909', '1911', '1913']

model = ['Horseless', 'Model T', 'OctoAuto', 'Bi-Autogo']
```

Into the following:

```
car_dict = {'Horsey':1899,'Horseless','Ford':1909,'Model T','Overland' : 1911, 'OctoAuto', 'Scripps-Booth' : 1913, 'Bi-Autogo'}
```

Here is what I did:

```
def car_data_merge(car_maker,car_model,car_year):
    car_dict = {}
    car_merge = []

    car_dict = defaultdict(partial(defaultdict,list))

    for (car_maker,car_model,car_year) in zip(car_maker,car_model,car_year):
         car_dict[car_year][car_model].append(car_maker)
    print(car_dict)
```

When I enter this I get:

```
{'Horsey': defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'1899': ['Horseless']})
```

Not all the data from list is shown and I don't want the `defaultdict` shown.

When I tried the following:

```
def car_data_merge(car_maker,car_data):
    car_dict = {}
    car_merge = []
    car_merge = zip(car_maker,car_data)  
    car_dict = dict(car_merge)
    print(car_dict)

    ###   car_data holds both year and model   ####
```

Only part of the data shows up:

```
'Horsey':'Horseless',':1909,'Model T
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You were on the right track with `zip`, but beware that:

> [The returned list is truncated in length to the length of the shortest argument sequence.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip)

If you're fine with that, you can zip your data into a list of tuples, zip the keys, and hand everything off to `dict()`.

If you'd like to handle missing values, checkout `itertools` [`izip_longest` (Python 2)](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) or [`zip_longest` (Python 3)](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) where

> [If the iterables are of uneven length, missing values are filled-in with *fillvalue*.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest)

```
try:
    # Python 2
    from itertools import izip_longest
    zip_longest = izip_longest
except ImportError:
    # Python 3
    from itertools import zip_longest

from pprint import pprint


def main():
    maker =['Horsey', 'Ford', 'Overland', 'Scripps-Booth', 'FutureX', 'FutureY']
    year = ['1899', '1909', '1911', '1913', '20xx']
    model = ['Horseless', 'Model T', 'OctoAuto', 'Bi-Autogo']

    car_data = dict(zip(maker, zip(year, model)))
    car_data_longest = {mk: (yr, md) for mk, yr, md in zip_longest(maker, year, model)}

    pprint(car_data)
    pprint(car_data_longest)
```

Output:

```
{'Ford': ('1909', 'Model T'),
 'Horsey': ('1899', 'Horseless'),
 'Overland': ('1911', 'OctoAuto'),
 'Scripps-Booth': ('1913', 'Bi-Autogo')}
{'Ford': ('1909', 'Model T'),
 'FutureX': ('20xx', None),
 'FutureY': (None, None),
 'Horsey': ('1899', 'Horseless'),
 'Overland': ('1911', 'OctoAuto'),
 'Scripps-Booth': ('1913', 'Bi-Autogo')}
```

Comment: Question: I never used izip before and I'm getting                     `values = itertools.izip(year, model)` 
`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'izip'` what should I do?

Comment: @ThomasJones It's `izip_longest`

Comment: @ThomasJones What version of Python are you using? `itertools.izip` was added in Python 2.3 and modified in Python 2.4. `itertools.izip_longest` is new in Python 2.6.

Comment: python 3.3.0 is what i'm using I just downloaded 2.6 and it does work. thanks! Also is there a way to use in python 3.3.0?

Comment: Ah, good point. `zip()` already returns an iterator in Python 3. `itertools.izip_longest` also becomes `itertools.zip_longest`. http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip, http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest

Comment: Thanks man!!! That was one of my main problems when printing out the dictionary. Unless every line was the same the dictionary was printed  wrong. You are number one!

Answer (score 8):

How's this:

```
>>> maker =['Horsey', 'Ford', 'Overland', 'Scripps-Booth']
>>> year = ['1899', '1909', '1911', '1913']
>>> model = ['Horseless', 'Model T', 'OctoAuto', 'Bi-Autogo']
>>> d = dict(zip(maker,zip(year,model)))
{'Overland': ('1911', 'OctoAuto'), 'Horsey': ('1899', 'Horseless'), 'Scripps-Booth': ('1913', 'Bi-Autogo'), 'Ford': ('1909', 'Model T')}
```

Comment: You don't need a call to `list`. Zip creates a list of tuples from which you can create a dictionary

Comment: Someone down voted this answer; could they please clarify why?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like what you want is:

```
{maker: (year, model) for maker, model, year in zip(car_maker,car_model,car_year)}
```

which will give you:

```
{'Horsey':(1899,'Horseless'),'Ford':(1909,'Model T'),'Overland':(1911,'OctoAuto')...}
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this the kind of thing you are looking for?

```
>>> car_dict = {maker[i]:[year[i], model[i]] for i in xrange(len(maker))}
>>> car_dict
{'Overland': ['1911', 'OctoAuto'], 'Horsey': ['1899', 'Horseless'], 'Scripps-Booth': ['1913', 'Bi-Autogo'], 'Ford': ['1909', 'Model T']}
```