# Merge three list to Dictionary but everything is out of place/not printed

Tags: python, list, merge, zip, missing-data

I asked this question yesterday

[Merging three lists into into one dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15698427/merging-three-lists-into-into-one-dictionary)

The number one answer was the most correct in what I needed

but re-looking at **MY** `automobile.txt file` I realized two things.

1. It has multiple car makers in the list and only **one** of each is listed.
2. Every data seems to be out place but a few.

I'm so close but so far.

**Here is what I Have**

Please **Note** if it makes a difference This is being read from a `.txt` file I appended and split the data into three list. I know the data is there. I checked.

```
from pprint import pprint
import string
import re

data_file = open("Automobil.txt", 'r')
try:
    from itertools import izip_longest
    zip_longest = izip_longest
except ImportError:
    from itertools import zip_longest

def formatting_list(data_file):
    year = []
    maker = []
    model = []
    for line in data_file:
        maker = (' '.join(line.split()[1:2]))
        year =  (' '.join(line.split()[0:1]))
        model = ((' '.join(line.split()[2:])))
    return maker,year,model

def car_data_merge(maker,year,model):
#This was the one suggested to me that I liked

     car_dict_longest = {mk: (yr, md) for mk, yr, md in zip_longest(maker,year,model)}
     pprint(car_dict_longest)
```

This is something similar to what I tried that another person showed me on the other page

```
  car_dict = {maker: (year, model) for maker, model, year in zip(car_maker,car_model,car_year)}
  print(car_dict)
```

After reading up on the uses of `izip` and how it is different from `zip`

I thought izip kept everything on place instead of it being temporary tuple.

This a small part of the `.txt` list where I think the problem is:

`year  = [1958,1909,1958,1958, 1961, 1961]`

`maker = [Ford,Ford,Lotus,MGA, Amphicar, Corvair]`

`model = [Edsel,Model T,Elite,Twin Cam]`

When ran this is what should happen

```
Ford: {1958 , Edsel}, Ford: {1909, Model T}, Lotus: {1958, Elite}, MGA :{1958, Twin Cam}, Amphicar:{1961}, Corvair:{1961}
```

Instead I get something like:

`Ford: {1958 , Edsel},  Lotus: {1958, MGA}, Amphicar:{1961, Corvair}`

Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you copy and paste the actual output of the dictionary (rather than "something like")? `Ford: {1958 , Edsel}, Lotus: {1958, MGA}, Amphicar:{1961, Corvair}` isn't anywhere close to Python syntax, especially when it looks like the inner parts should be tuples

Comment: `maker` is the key and appears twice, so the second tuple of values for Ford will overwrite the first. A key may occur only once in a dictionary.

Comment: @DavidRobinson Sorry about that, the thing is the data seems to move or rotate everything I press print. I would gladly show the actual as typed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Recommendation

You could do a dictionary of lists of tuples. [Defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) is your friend.

## Code

```
from collections import defaultdict

year = [1958, 1909, 1958, 1958, 1961, 1961]
maker = ['Ford', 'Ford', 'Lotus', 'MGA', 'Amphicar', 'Corvair']
model = ['Edsel', 'Model T', 'Elite', 'Twin Cam', '', '']

d = defaultdict(list)
for maker, model, year in zip(maker, model, year):
    d[maker].append((model, year))
```

## Result

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> 
>>> year = [1958, 1909, 1958, 1958, 1961, 1961]
>>> maker = ['Ford','Ford','Lotus','MGA', 'Amphicar', 'Corvair']
>>> model = ['Edsel', 'Model T', 'Elite', 'Twin Cam', "", ""]
>>> 
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for maker, model, year in zip(maker, model, year):
...     d[maker].append((model, year))
... 
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(dict(d))
{'Amphicar': [('', 1961)],
 'Corvair': [('', 1961)],
 'Ford': [('Edsel', 1958), ('Model T', 1909)],
 'Lotus': [('Elite', 1958)],
 'MGA': [('Twin Cam', 1958)]}
```

You can also use your `izip_longest`:

```
from itertools import izip_longest

...

d = defaultdict(list)
for maker, model, year in izip_longest(maker, model, year):
    d[maker].append((model, year))
```

Then you get None for the other values.

Comment: Thankyou. with what you added and a little tweaking and everything worked FINALLY!! Thank you for your input.