# Nesting a list of lists as value in Nested Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have three pieces of data that I need to nest in a dictionary using `python`:

1. ID (can be repeted)
2. Date (of action - can be repeted)
3. actions (lists of words that are associated to an ID and a date)

**Example of data** (tab-separated):

```
UID DATE    ACTIONS
abc123  12/25/2016  break, pullover
abc123  12/25/2016  stop
abc123  10/15/2015  break, pullover, turn
def456  6/14/2015   turn, wash, skid
def456  11/24/2016  stop, wash, pullover, break
ghi789  2/12/2015   pullover, stop
```

**CODE - revised with @moogle comments**

```
from collections import defaultdict

date = ['12/25/16','12/25/16','10/15/2015','6/14/2015','11/24/2016','2/12/2015']
uid = ['abc123','abc123', 'abc123','def456', 'def456', 'ghi789']
action = [['break', 'pullover'],['stop'],['break','pullover','turn'],['turn','wash','skid'],['stop','wash','pullover','break'],['pullover','stop']]

d = defaultdict(list)
for uid, date, action in zip(uid, date, action):
    d[id].append((date,action))

    print dict(d)
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT**
The desired output is a nested dictionary of lists.
Where the parent `key` is the ID and the parent `value` is nested dictionaries in which the nested `key` is the date and the nested `value` is a list of lists (actions).

**current actual output**

```
{'ghi789': [('2/12/2015', ['pullover', 'stop'])], 'def456': [('6/14/2015', ['turn', 'wash', 'skid']), ('11/24/2016', ['stop', 'wash', 'pullover', 'break'])], 'abc123': [('12/25/16', ['break', 'pullover']), ('12/25/16', ['stop']), ('10/15/2015', ['break', 'pullover', 'turn'])]}

**desired output**
{'abc123':[{'12/25/2016':[['break', 'pullover'],['stop']]}, {'10/15/2015':[['break','pullover','turn']]}],'def456':[{'6/14/2015':[['turn','wash','skid'],['stop','wash','pullover','break']},'ghi789':{'2/12/2915':[['pullover','stop']]}]}
```

I tried to obtain the above output with the above code, which I adapted from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15713825/merge-three-list-to-dictionary-but-everything-is-out-of-place-not-printed?noredirect=1&lq=1) and looked up [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889385/list-of-dictionaries-in-a-dictionary-in-python). However, I continuosuly am getting errors. I think it has to do with the fact that I am trying to nest in the value a list of lists, and I am unsure what direction to go in to fix it.

Comment: `for id, date, action in zip(id, date, action):`... You overwrite your list variables with the for loop iterators...

Comment: Please don't do this... Use objects!

Comment: What is your actual output now? What error message are you getting?

Comment: @Fruitspunchsamurai the output I am getting right now is superficial, I copy it here - "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple"

Comment: You forgot a comma between two lists, which is why you get the TypeError. Also, you shouldn't use `id` as a variable name.

Comment: @moogle, that takes care of the error, but does not give OP the desired output as he specified.

Comment: @moogle You are right, 1. i edited question for variable name `id` -> `uid` and 2. with the comma, I know longer get error, but the output is still not desired. I fixed the code and put current output in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that an object based approach is much better for these data.

You can do something like:

```
class Event:
    def __init__(self, ID, date, actions):
        self.ID=ID
        self.date=date
        self.actions=actions

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'ID: {} date: {} actions: {}'.format(self.ID, self.date, self.actions)
```

Then create a list of objects like so:

```
 >>> objs=[Event(id_, d, actions) for id_, d, actions in zip(uid, date, action)]
 >>> objs
 [ID: abc123 date: 12/25/16 actions: ['break', 'pullover'], ID: abc123 date: 12/25/16 actions: ['stop'], ID: abc123 date: 10/15/2015 actions: ['break', 'pullover', 'turn'], ID: def456 date: 6/14/2015 actions: ['turn', 'wash', 'skid'], ID: def456 date: 11/24/2016 actions: ['stop', 'wash', 'pullover', 'break'], ID: ghi789 date: 2/12/2015 actions: ['pullover', 'stop']]
```

Then that list of actions / events can be sorted, analyzed, saved as you wish.

Sort by date:

```
>>> sorted(objs, key=lambda o: o.date)
[ID: abc123 date: 10/15/2015 actions: ['break', 'pullover', 'turn'], ID: def456 date: 11/24/2016 actions: ['stop', 'wash', 'pullover', 'break'], ID: abc123 date: 12/25/16 actions: ['break', 'pullover'], ID: abc123 date: 12/25/16 actions: ['stop'], ID: ghi789 date: 2/12/2015 actions: ['pullover', 'stop'], ID: def456 date: 6/14/2015 actions: ['turn', 'wash', 'skid']]
```

By event:

```
>>> [o for o in objs if 'stop' in o.actions]
[ID: abc123 date: 12/25/16 actions: ['stop'], ID: def456 date: 11/24/2016 actions: ['stop', 'wash', 'pullover', 'break'], ID: ghi789 date: 2/12/2015 actions: ['pullover', 'stop']]
```

And then creating a dict similar to what you want (even though that example is not a legal Python dict....) is fairly obvious:

```
di={o.ID:[] for o in objs}
for user in di:
    di[user].append({o.date:o.actions for o in objs if o.ID==user})

>>> di
{'ghi789': [{'2/12/2015': ['pullover', 'stop']}], 'def456': [{'6/14/2015': ['turn', 'wash', 'skid'], '11/24/2016': ['stop', 'wash', 'pullover', 'break']}], 'abc123': [{'10/15/2015': ['break', 'pullover', 'turn'], '12/25/16': ['stop']}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for me, if I add the missing comma in the 'action' list...

I get the output:

```
{'ghi789': [('2/12/2015', ['pullover', 'stop'])], 'def456': [('6/14/2015', ['turn', 'wash', 'skid']), ('11/24/2016', ['stop', 'wash', 'pullover', 'break'])], 'abc123': [('12/25/16', ['break', 'pullover']), ('12/25/16', ['stop']), ('10/15/2015', ['break', 'pullover', 'turn'])]}
```

What about the following solution:

```
from collections import defaultdict

date = ['12/25/16','12/25/16','10/15/2015','6/14/2015','11/24/2016','2/12/2015']
uid = ['abc123','abc123', 'abc123','def456', 'def456', 'ghi789']
action = [['break', 'pullover'],['stop'],['break','pullover','turn'],['turn','wash','skid'],['stop','wash','pullover','break'],['pullover','stop']]

d = defaultdict(dict)
for uid, date, action in zip(uid, date, action):
    d[uid].setdefault(date,[]).append(action)

print dict(d)
```

output:

```
{'ghi789': {'2/12/2015': [['pullover', 'stop']]}, 'def456': {'6/14/2015': [['turn', 'wash', 'skid']], '11/24/2016': [['stop', 'wash', 'pullover', 'break']]}, 'abc123': {'10/15/2015': [['break', 'pullover', 'turn']], '12/25/16': [['break', 'pullover'], ['stop']]}}
```

Comment: This does not give OP the desired output.